# React Native: Recurring Could Not Connect to Developtment Server error (timeout?)

Tags: react-native

I've been trying out React Native lately and I got everything setup right.

Im running my Android Virtual Device and my RN app is displaying and reloading just fine.

However, every after a certain amount of time, when i hit RR (refresh) i get this error:

[image]

The only way I can seem to recover from this is if I rerun React native command:

react-native run-android

After that, it's ok again..... until after a few minutes, I get that dreaded RED SCREEN OF DEATH again.

What could be causing this? Timeout of some sort?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons for that.

- You have problem on JS files you are using (you can see errors on
  react packager)
- You are closing the react packager terminal after run your app
- It closes itself automatically with some terminal reasons

Do you get any error on react packager?